# Special character coding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, javascript-framework

I want to define a delete special character in my js code. But the issue is that when I use `chr(46)` it gives me syntax error.

Any idea how can I use chr(46) in my JS code?

```
storageVAR){storageVAR += chr(8);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "define a delete special character"? What is `chr()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS doesn't have `chr()`. Its equivalent is `String.fromCharCode(65);` (that gives A - just put whatever number you need).